# v-if and v-else not working after data array change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Depending on the array 'r.meta.fields' a specific sort icon of each column needs to be shown. When the template is rendering, it is working correctly. But when the array change, the template isn't changing anymore.

```
<th v-for="field in r.meta.fields">
        {{field.label}}

    <a href="#" @click.prevent="sortField(field)">
        <div class="fa fa-sort-up" v-if="field.sort_direction === 'desc'"></div>
        <div class="fa fa-sort-down" v-else-if="field.sort_direction === 'asc'"></div>
        <div class="fa fa-sort" v-else-if="field.sortable"></div>
    </a>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using something like

```
r.meta.fields = newValue
```

then this won't work.

you should use

```
Vue.set(r.meta.fields, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

document here: [vue update array](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

Comment: Thank you. In my case the whole r array is replaced for a new one. So I don't have a indexOfItem to be updated. Do you have a solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a mapping for the sort icons and handle the changes on click:

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    const iconMap = {
      sort: {
        'asc': 'fa-sort-up',
        'desc': 'fa-sort-down'
      }
    };

    return {
      r: {
        meta: {
          fields: [
            {
              label: 'field #1',
              sortable: false,
              sort_direction: 'asc',
              icon: ''
            }, 
            {
              label: 'field #2',
              sortable: true,
              sort_direction: 'desc',
              icon: iconMap.sort['desc']// Initially sortable in descending order
            }
          ]
        }
      },

      iconMap
    }
  },

  methods: {
    sortField(field) {
      let direction = (field.sort_direction === 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
      let icon = this.iconMap.sort[direction] || '';

      field.sort_direction = direction;
      field.icon = icon;
    }
  }
})
```

#### Template or HTML

```vue
<div id="app">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th v-for="field in r.meta.fields" :key="field.label">
       {{field.label}}

       <a href="#"
        :class="field.icon"
        @click.prevent="sortField(field)"></a>
    </th>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated to handle array of fields. Let me know if that works for you.